# visual studio 2012 show hidden tags in design mode

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2012, designmode

In visual studio if you have an hidden field,

**eg:**

```
<div style="display:none">
   This content is not visible in design time 
</div>
```

In design mode one cannot see the content of the div.

Are there any settings in **Visual Studio 2012** to make invisible tags to be seen in design mode?

Answer (score 2):

On the Visual Studio menu go to View -> Visual Aids.

You should see CSS Display:none Elements and/or CSS Visibility:hidden Elements.

Answer (score 0):

> To help you edit a page, Design view displays certain elements, such
>   as hidden fields, that would normally not be visible in the browser.
>   Design view also displays gray boxes or other representations of
>   ASP.NET server controls, such as data source controls, that do not
>   render markup at run time.

**To toggle markers on and off for non-graphic HTML elements in Design view**

1. On the View menu, click Details.
2. To set markers to display whenever you open a Web page in Design view, do the following:

   - On the Tools menu, click Options.
   - Under HTML Designer, select the Display check box.
   - Under Display Options, select the Show details for
     non-visible elements check box.

**To display or conceal table borders in Design view**

1. On the View menu, click Visible Borders.

This displays edges around tables and frames that would otherwise not appear.

1. To set borders to display whenever you open a Web page in Design view, do the following:

   - On the Tools menu, click Options.
   - Under HTML Designer, select the Display check box.
   - Under Display Options, select the Show details for non-visible elements check box.

**To mark ASP.NET server controls**

1. On the Tools menu, click Options.
2. Under HTML Designer, select the Display check box.
3. Under Display Options, select the Show glyphs for server controls check box.

## [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178152%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks, but i don't have these options. under tools\options\html designer\display\i only can chose color for dysplayed elements!

Comment: infact the source you provided applies only to vs 2008 and 2005